# Embed JS into Xamarin

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, xamarin

My app relies on web-scraping, for which there don't seem to be as many good libraries in the .NET world as there are in e.g. JS.  What is the best way to embed JS into a Xamarin project, if there is a way?  Preferably with the minimum of effort to get this working across platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the WebHybrid classes: https://github.com/sami1971/SimplyMobile/tree/master/Core/SimplyMobile.Web

These work for iOS, Android and WP8. They are using web views but you can use them just as JS containers and execute JS through them. For serialization/deserialization there are several JSON serializers to choose from.

Comment: Thanks Skall, nice library.